# How to replace more than one character in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to replace multiple whole characters, except those in combinations...?

The below code replaces multiple characters, but it also disturbing those in combinations.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('a,ca,va,ea,r,y,q,b,g','(a|y|q|g)','X') RESULT FROM dual;
```

Current output:

```
RESULT 
--------------------
X,cX,vX,eX,r,X,X,b,X
```

Expected output:

```
RESULT 
------------------------
'X,ca,va,ea,r,X,X,b,X
```

I just want to replace only separate whole characters('a','y','q','g'), but not the 1 in combinations('ca','va','ea')...

Comment: Use nested replace and if you want to replace only one character you can replace 'a,' with 'x' instead of 'a'.

Comment: Using nested replace also replacing the 'a' in combinations., But i just want to replace only separate 'a', except those in combinations...

Answer (score 1):

Because you are delimiting with a comma ',' you can combine that like **',a,'**

and this will replace only single a's.

Comment: what about first and last "a"?

Comment: @Pravin Satav: That's easy; you'd add a comma in front and end and then remove them again after having applied the replace operation.

Answer (score 1):

you can try follows:

```
with t as
    (
        select 'a,ca,va,ea,r,y,q,b,g' str
        from dual
    )
select substr(sys_connect_by_path(regexp_replace(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level), '^(a|y|q|g)$', 'X'), ','), 2) as str
from t
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
    connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(str, '[^,]*')) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would look for word boundaries, which is \b, and which is unfortunately not supported by Oracle's regexp_replace.

So let's look for a non-word character \W or the beginning ^ or ending $ of the text.

```
select
  regexp_replace('a,ca,va,ea,r,y,q,b,g','(^|$|\W)(a|y|q|g)(^|$|\W)','\1X\3') as result
from dual;
```

In order to not remove the non-word characters, we must have them in the replace string: \1 for the expression in the first parenteses, \3 for the ones in the third. Thus we only change the expression in the second parentheses, which is a, y, q or g, with X.

Unfortunately above gives

```
X,ca,va,ea,r,X,q,b,X
```

The q was not replaced, because we recognize ',y,' thus being positioned a 'g,' whereas we'd need to be positioned at ',g,' to recognize g as a word, too.

So we need to replace in iterations (i.e. recursively):

```
with results(txt, num) as
(
  select 'a,ca,va,ea,r,y,q,b,g' as txt, 0 as num from dual
  union all
  select regexp_replace(txt, '(^|$|\W)(a|y|q|g)(^|$|\W)','\1X\3'), num + 1 as num
  from results
  where txt <> regexp_replace(txt, '(^|$|\W)(a|y|q|g)(^|$|\W)','\1X\3')
)
select max(txt) keep (dense_rank last order by num) as result
from results;
```

EDIT: Kevin Esche is right; of course one has to do it only twice. Hence you can also do:

```
select
  regexp_replace(txt, search_str, replace_str) as result 
from
(
  select 
    regexp_replace(txt, search_str, replace_str) as txt, search_str, replace_str 
  from 
  (
    select 
      'a,ca,va,ea,r,y,q,y,q,b,g' as txt,
      '(^|$|\W)(a|y|q|g)(^|$|\W)' as search_str,
      '\1X\3' as replace_str 
    from dual
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly oracle doesn´t support lookahead and lookbehind. But this is a solution i came up with.

```
SELECT regexp_replace
          (regexp_replace
              ('a,ca,va,ea,r,y,q,b,g',
               '^[ayqg](,)|(,)[ayqg](,)|(,)[ayqg]$',
               '\2\4X\1\3'),'(,)[ayqg](,)','\1X\2') 
RESULT FROM dual;
```

I had to use the regexp twice sadly, since it doesn´t find two similar values following after each other and replacing it. `..,a,y,..` is getting replaced as `..,X,y,..`. So the second call replaces the missing [ayqg] with the exact values. In the first inner regexp call replaces the first and last values.

Maybe this could be simplified into one expression, but i am not that conform with the regex from oracle.

As a explanation i am grouping the commata and basicly replace every `,[ayqg],` with `,X,` by backreferencing the commata

Answer (score 0):

```
with replaced_values as (
SELECT case when length(val)=1 then regexp_replace(val,'(a|y|q|g)','X') else val end new_val, lvl 
from (
  SELECT regexp_substr('a,ca,va,ea,r,y,q,b,g','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) val, level lvl FROM dual
connect by regexp_substr('a,ca,va,ea,r,y,q,b,g','[^,]+',1, LEVEL) is not null
 ) all_values
 )
select lISTAGG(new_val, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lvl) RESULT 
 from replaced_values
```

This statement pivots data into rows and replaces only lines wich contains one character.
Data are then unpivoted in one rows

Answer (score 0):

This sql works also with empty entries like 'a,,,b,c' and more complex regular expressions:

```
with t as
 (select ',a,,ca,va,ea,bbb,ba,r,y,q,b,g,,,' as str,
         ',' as delimiter,
         '(a|y|q|g|ea|[b]*)' as regexp_expr,
         'X' as replace_expr
    from dual)

 (select substr (sys_connect_by_path(regexp_replace(substr(str,
              decode(level - 1, 0, 0, instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1)) + 1,
          decode(instr(str, ',', 1, level),
                 0,
                 length(str),
                 instr(str, ',', 1, level) - 1) -
          decode(level - 1, 0, 0, instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1))),
                    '^' || regexp_expr || '$',
                    replace_expr), ','), 2)
    from t
     where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(str, '[^'|| delimiter||']')) + 1)
```

Result

```
,X,,ca,va,X,X,ba,r,X,X,X,X,,,
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't Know much Oracle, but I would have thought something like this could work. Assuming the delimiter is always a comma.

```
 SELECT 
 regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace('a,ca,va,ea,r,y,q,b,g','(,a,|,y,|,q,|,g,)',',X,') ,'(,a,|,y,|,q,|,g,)',',X,'), '(^a,|^y,|^q,|^g,)','X,'), '(,a$|,y$|,q$|,g$)',',X'), '(^a$|^y$|^q$|^g$)','X')
 RESULT FROM test;
```

The first two parts replaces  a single character in commas in the middle, the third part gets those at the start of the string, the fourth is for the end of the string and the fifth is for when then string has just one character.

This answer might will be simplifiable by advanced Regexp use.

Answer (score -1):

How i can replace words?

RS & OS ===> D, LS & IS ==== > 
SECTION_ID  Output required
1-LS-1991      1-P-1991
1-IS-1991       1-P-1991
1-RS-1991      1- D- 1991
1-OS-1991      1-D-1991

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please provide an SQL select which does the job.

Comment: Could you tell me how i use replace

Comment: RS & OS ===> D, LS & IS ==== >                                                  
 SECTION_ID  
1-LS-1991      
1-IS-1991       
1-RS-1991      
1-OS-1991

Comment: Output required 1-P-1991,  1-P-1991  , 1-D-1991, 1-D-1991

Comment: Do you want to know how `replace` works? If yes: Ask a new question!

Comment: Yeah,  I have a column section id which  has 1-LS-1991 ,1-IS-1991, 1-RS-1991 ,1-OS-1991  I want  to replace  LS with P and RS with D How i can?

Comment: Lots of result are there of this ids i want to change there where LS and IS with P and  Rs and OS with D , have you understand?

Comment: Comments are not the place to ask questions: use the blue button `Ask Question` in the upper right corner.